# Unable to receive FCM push message

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am unable to receive the push message which is send using FCM. 
I'm using PHP to send the message, in that it shows the message is successfully send along with the following status

```
{\"multicast_id\":4966432624241188413,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1514537346602738%3a021553f9fd7ecd\"}]}
```

But this message is not receiving in the android application.
Here is the code which i used in android

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            Log.e("Received",remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        }
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

**I have cross checked the firebase token. Both are same still am not able to receive the message**

Comment: Maybe you have problem with sending and getting FCM Token to your server so your not getting it right.

Comment: can you test it from https://firebase.corp.google.com/project/project-name/notification/compose

Comment: I have checked that, token registered to the device and the token in which the message is sending is same @LesterL.

Comment: did you add server key in the header?

Comment: @HarikumarAlangode yes I have

Comment: i have the same problem